# VueJS Axios JSON slice/filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm new in programming and I'm going to be frontend developer. As part of the exercises i'm trying to do a simple web-app.

But to the point.

I got stuck while trying to filter/slice JSON object - only what I get from the console is: "slice/filter is not a function". I know that those functions are intended for arrays but I have no idea how to conver JSON object to JSON array. I looked a lot of staff in the Internet and tried to implement it but unsuccessfully...

There is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="class">
        <section v-if="errored">
            <p>We're sorry, we're not able to retrieve this information at the moment, please try back later</p>
        </section>

        <section v-else>
            <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>

            <div class="row" v-else>
                <div>
                    <div v-for="vehicle in filteredVehicles">
                        <img v-for="car in vehicle.cars" v-bind:src="car.url" v-bind:alt="car.name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                vehicles: [],
                loading: true,
                errored: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get('https://urlurlurl/vehicles.json')
                .then(response => (this.vehicles= response.data))
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
        computed: {
            filteredVehicles: function () {
                return this.vehicles.filter(function (v) {
                    return v.name === ('aaa' || 'bbb')
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Sample of how the data is structured:

```
{
  "1": {
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "age": {
      "1": {
        "name": "",
        "url": ""
      },
      "3": {
        "name": "",
        "url": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "age": {
      "6": {
        "name": "",
        "url": ""
      },
      "7": {
        "name": "",
        "url": ""
      }
    }
  }
  // etc.
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: We'll need to see the structure of your JSON to know how to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your data is an object of key/value pairs. Unfortunately, the majority of browsers don't support [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which will give you an array of *just* the values of the object:

```
return Object.values(this.vehicles)    // Array of vehicle objects
  .filter(function (v) {
    return v.name === ('aaa' || 'bbb')
  })
```

...but there is an [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method which is largely supported, so you can get to the values with a two-step process:

```
return Object.keys(this.vehicles)     // Array of keys in the JSON obj
  .map(key => this.vehicles[key])     // Array of vehicle objects
  .filter(function (v) {
    return v.name === ('aaa' || 'bbb')
  })
```

Or if you want to use something like `lodash`, that gives you some more convenient functions for dealing with manipulating objects.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I'll check it in the morning because now is the middle of the night and I am exhausted after a long time spent in front of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your app.js file

```
Vue.filter('snippet',function (val) {
    return val.slice(0,100);
})
```

and when you want to use it just put snippest in your html like this.

```
<p class="card-text mb-auto">{{product.description | snippet}}</p>
```